# Python matrix row shifting(Also column)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, shift

Is there any way that I can shift specific row in python? (It would be nice if numpy is used).
I want

```
[[1,2],
[3,4]]
```

to be

```
[[1,2],
[4,3]].
```

Also for the column would be nice!

```
[[1,2],
[3,4]]
```

to be

```
[[1,4],
[3,2]]
```

.

Thank you.

Comment: Are your matrices always 2x2?

Answer (score 1):

`np.roll` is your friend.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> x[1]
array([3, 4])
>>> np.roll(x[1],1)
array([4, 3])
>>> x[1] = np.roll(x[1],1)
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 3]])
>>> x[1] = np.roll(x[1],1)
>>> x[:,1]
array([2, 4])
>>> x[:,1] = np.roll(x[:,1],1)
>>> x
array([[1, 4],
       [3, 2]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the row shifting you can do:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(5, 5)
row_no = 2
matrix[row_no, :] = np.array([matrix[row_no, -1]] + list(matrix[row_no, :-1]))
```

and similarly for column shifting you can simply switch the dimension orders.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.rand(5, 5)
col_no = 2
matrix[:, col_no] = np.array([matrix[-1, col_no]] + list(matrix[:-1, col_no]))
```

Comment: It helped me a lot!